# How to make array type schema objects appear one in a row? react-jsonschema-form

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-jsonschema-forms

I am using react-jsonschema-form to create a form. Single components are displaying fine but array components are coming in a row. How Can I make them appear one array object in a row so that everytime I click Add button , new array object is rendered  in new row. Code is as follows:

```
    const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    Name: { type: "string", title: "Name", default: "A new Task" },
    Title: { type: "object", properties: { First: { type: "string" }, Second: { type: "string" } } },
    XYZ: { type: "array", items: { type: "object", properties: { Third: { type: "string" }, Forth: { type: "boolean", enum: [true, false], enumNames: ["True", "False"] } } } }
  }
}

const uiSchema = {
  "ui:order": ["Name", "Title", "Done"],
  Name: { "ui:widget": "textarea" },
  Title: { First: { "ui:widget": "textarea" }, Second: { "ui:widget": "textarea" } },
  XYZ: { items: { Third: { "ui:widget": "textarea" }, Forth: { "ui:widget": "radio", "ui:options": { inline: true } } }, "ui:options": { orderable: false, removable: true, inline: false } }
}
```

Form Code is as Follows:

```
<Form schema={schema}
              // formData = {defaultData}
              uiSchema={uiSchema}
              onChange={log("changed")}
              onSubmit={SubmitRoutine}
              onError={ErrorRoutine}
            />
```

As shown in the following picture Array XYZ objects are fixed width and displaying next to each other. I want them full width and every object in new row. I am using React and Bootstrap4
[image]
Also very time I have to even add first object by clicking Plus button. I want first object to appear itself. Please let me know how may I fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this](https://github.com/audibene-labs/react-jsonschema-form-layout) library. It allows laying out your form using bootstrap-grid.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved with [pure CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction), provided there is no need to reflect order in the model:

```css
/* class of a wrapping element */
.array-item-list {
    display: flex;
    /* column, column-reverse, row, row-reverse */
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```